# NPM update failed. Error says to remove file?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-update

Im having a hard time trying to update npm it crashes when i run npm i -g npm and it says i have to remove an existing file "file already exists, symlink '../../../lib/node_modules/npm/man/man1/npx.1' -> '/usr/local/share/man/man1/npx.1' Remove the existing file and try again". After that i try to run a npm command and my terminal says "zsh: command not found: npm". Ive tried to look for a file under that but no luck. If anyone has a better understanding of this i would appreciate the help!

Comment: `Did you try installing node.js again?`

Comment: Thanks for the tip it seemed like a node update and a restart helped. Was able to update with no errors thanks